# UIWebView won't load new URL

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiwebview, uinavigationcontroller

I have a UITableView that displays peoples names of whatever department is chosen. When you then select a person in the TableView, it loads a detail page with labels with all their contact info; then at the bottom it loads their website in a smaller UIWebView.

If you choose a person, view their info, go back, then choose another person in that same department, the UIWebView does not reload the new selected person's website, it remains on the site of the person whom was first selected.

I have tried all night to get this working; I am sure its something simple.

I have tried setting the webView to nil, and releasing it in the viewDidDisappear and viewWillDisappear (the ones that get called when you go back to the list of people after viewing one).

I have this set up as a UINavigationController.

The labels for the selected person details all update for the selected person, but the UIWebView just doesn't want to reload. Any help appreciated!!

**EDIT**
Sorry I forgot to add the code, it was way too late when I posted this lol. But here where all my labels and things get updated (I took those lines out to clean it up on here).

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"willAppear");
    [[self navigationItem] setTitle:[selectedPerson professorLName]];

url = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[selectedPerson departmentWebsite]];
NSLog(@"%@", url);
req = [[NSURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
[webView loadRequest:req];
webView.scalesPageToFit = YES;

}

- (void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSLog(@"willDis");
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
    [webView release];
    webView = nil;
url = nil;
}

- (void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL)animated 
{
    NSLog(@"didDisappear");
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
    [webView release];
    webView = nil;
    url = nil;
}
```

Comment: It seems like you forgot to include code in your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove your code in `viewWillDisappear` and `viewDidDisappear`, and try this:

```
-(void) viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    [self.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:selectedPerson.departmentWebsite]]];
}
```

Keep in mind that if you put this in `-viewWillAppear`, the page will reload when you switch tabs (if you have any) or when the app comes to the foreground. For that reason, I prefer to load the url when I push the detail view controller:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
        SimpleWebViewController* detailViewController = [[SimpleWebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SimpleWebView" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:detailViewController animated:YES];
        [detailViewController.webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]]];
        [detailViewController release];
    }
}
```

Hope that helps!

Comment: I tried what you were doing, but it still is not reloading the page. I did realize when the page will not reload. There are 2 instances when the detail view gets pushed. It gets pushed when you select a department and then choose a person, and then the webView reloads for each person. You can also search by name, so if you search Ryan, 4 names come up; only when you select a person here, go back, and select another person in the search results that the webView does not reload. Its hard to explain but hopefully you get what I mean

Comment: I resolved the issues by simply adding a button that loads the department website in a separate UIWebView, instead of loading it in a smaller UIWebView within the detail view

Answer (score 0):

spit the url to your console. it sounds like you may be passing the same url.
but yeah fluchtpunkt is right, lets see your code.

Comment: As you can see I am spitting the URL to the console, and it is printing out the correct URL for the person selected, but not loading it, thats why I am so confused, the request isn't reloading each time.

Comment: does the webview actually reload the same page or remain static with the pre-existing content?

Comment: It remains static with the pre-existing content.. I have tried to force a reload in several places and I cannot get it to.